# Maximum value of newform from Galois representation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

One can attach $\ell$-adic Galois representations to holomorphic cuspidal newforms of weight $2$ on the upper half-plane.

If a newform is $L^2$-normalized, can one extract its maximum value from the Galois representation?

Comment: I think you can only attach a Galois-representation to cohomological cuspidal automorphic reprepresentations (and their newforms). The maximum value of a newform is a subtle problem, even for holomorphic newforms on the upper half-plane, and I don't know of any connection with Galois-representations.

Comment: I had holomorphic modular forms in mind.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question: isn't a holomorphic modular form (cuspidal or not) unbounded on the upper half-plane ? It is y^{k/2}|f(x+iy)| which is bounded.

Comment: @HenriCohen: In the sup-norm problem for holomorphic cusp forms, one studies $y^{k/2}|f(x+iy)|$, as you suggest. I am sure the OP had this function in mind (and so did I).

Comment: I added the adjective "holomorphic" to the post. Note that there are Maass forms of all weights on the upper half-plane, including those that do not come from holomorphic cusp forms (cf. Henri Cohen's remark).

Comment: @GHfromMO Does the OP mean an approximate value for the maximum? If so then the key should be to find the level from the ramification.

Comment: @reuns: Perhaps you should ask the OP about what he/she means.